# How to traverse SharePoint site collection with Multi Factor Authentication (MFA) enabled?

Tags: winforms, sharepoint-online, multi-factor-authentication

I have a Winforms app that displays a SharePoint site collection and document libraries in a `TreeView` control with hierarchy according to the site level.

I use the following code for account with MFA enabled

```
            AuthenticationManager authManager = new AuthenticationManager();            
            using (ClientContext clientContext = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                WebCollection site = web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
                clientContext.Load(site, we => we.Include(w => w.Url, w => w.Title));
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                teamSites = site.ToDictionary(w => w.Url, w => w.Title);
                teamSites = teamSites.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value);
                ListCollection libraries = web.Lists;
                clientContext.Load(libraries, l => l.Include(li => li.DefaultViewUrl, li => li.BaseType, li => li.Title, li => li.BaseTemplate, li => li.Hidden));
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                documentLibraries = libraries.Where(lib => lib.BaseType == BaseType.DocumentLibrary && lib.Hidden == false && lib.BaseTemplate == 101).ToList();
            }
```

The team site URL will be added to each `TreeNode` in my `TreeView`, whenever user clicks on a `TreeNode`, it will need to load the sub-sites and document libraries using the above method. However, every time it loads, the pop up shows and disappears because user is already logged in. Is there anyway to prevent it popping up every single time user clicks on the site `TreeNode`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use app authentication.

[demo thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d33f5818-f112-42fb-becf-3cf14ac5f940/app-only-token-issue-unauthorized-access?forum=appsforsharepoint)

```
//Get the realm for the URL
                string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(siteUri);

                //Get the access token for the URL.  
                //   Requires this app to be registered with the tenant
                string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(
                    TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal,
                    siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;

                //Get client context with access token
                using (var clientContext =
                    TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(
                        siteUri.ToString(), accessToken))
                {
```

Comment: Which namespace can I find the `TokenHelper`? My Resharper automatically adds the Microsoft Graph Client namespace which doesn't have the above methods

Comment: Will it work with Sharepoint Online account with MFA enabled?